# The first day and the last day of the month

Tags: php, date, datetime

Can someone help me with this, I need get the following values:

- `$startTime` must be the first of a month with `00:00:00`, otherwise

  invalid time
- `end_date` from `$_GET` must always be the first of a month with time `00:00:00`, otherwise `invalid date`
- `$defaultEndTime` must be the first of current month with time `00:00:00`
- `$endTime` must be the first of a month with `00:00:00`, otherwise

  invalid time
- difference between `$startTime` and `$endTime` must be exactly one month

I tried:

```
    $end_date=new DateTime();
    $end_date->format('Y-m-js 00:00:00');
```

I tried to use `datedif` to get the different `startTime` end `endTime` but I don't know how to get one month.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, the code I was working also included mysql. But this has nothing to do with mysql I should not have selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=> Try this code..

```
<?php

echo date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime('first day of this month'));

echo "<br/>";

echo date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime('last day of this month'));

?>
```

**Demo :-** [`https://eval.in/933378`](https://eval.in/933378)

Answer (score 1):

To get first day and last day of month

```
    $date = '2018-01-11';
    // First day with 00:00:00
    echo date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', strtotime($date ));
    echo '<br>';
    // Last day with 00:00:00
    echo date('Y-m-t 00:00:00', strtotime($date ));
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
2018-01-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $startDate = date('01-m-Y 00:00:00',strtotime('this month')); // First day of current month

 echo $startDate;

 $endDate =  date("t-m-Y 00:00:00", strtotime($startDate ));// Last date of current month. 
 //'t' provide last day of month means if, it is Jan then get 31 
 //and also if current month is Feb then t provide 28.It's happend same as other months.

 echo $endDate ;
```

Lets Today is 11-01-2018. Then output :

```
  01-01-2018 00:00:00
  31-01-2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.